# I found a non-continuous differentiable function, where's my mistake?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let's define the following function:

> $f(x)=x^2$, if $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=1$

We know this function isn't differentiable at $x=0$ because it isn't continuous there. However using the definition of the derivative we have:

> $f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=0$

Where's my mistake?

Comment: How does $(h^2-1)/h$ go to zero? Seems like it will blow up to infinity.

Comment: @ziggurism I got it! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}= \lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{h^2-1}{h}\\
> =\lim_{h\to 0} h -\frac{1}{h}= 0 - \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}$$

And of course the limit as $h$ goes to $0$ of $\frac{1}{h}$ does not exist.